# user_ratings_total No longer available in google places API. Alternative for getting total number of reviews?

Tags: google-places-api

As of today (5/25/2016) there seems to no longer be data for user_ratings_total in the Google Places API. I use this to get the total number of reviews for a business. Is there an alternative method to getting this data?

Comment: It looks like user_ratings_total was undocumented property (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlaceResult). Google can remove undocumented properties without any notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try the [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/), see in particular the documentation section [Work with Review Data](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data).

You'll need to [Request access to the API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#request-access-to-the-api).

Comment: This is technically the solution to my issue. I'm not too happy about it though because it seems like I have to request access to the API for each business separately as it only grants access to those businesses controlled by that Google My Business account. We have 20 locations (and growing) and each location unfortunately has it's own account. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem. but when i follow the steps in GMB it gives me the following errors:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983900/total-reviews-are-no-longer-getting-in-google-places-api-and-method-not-found-i?noredirect=1

P.S> I have enabled the api for my project. If you have solved the issue Please share your solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like Google to reinstate the previously undocumented user_ratings_total result key (or something similar), then please go to: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3484 and add your vote for this feature to be officially added.

This issue was "Acknowledged" by Google way back on Jun 3, 2013 and is still open as such (other similar issues like https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9824 have been "closed" with status like "WorkingAsIntended").

Hopefully if we get enough up votes then maybe they will see the need and put it back in and make it official (as opposed to undocumented).

(Unfortunately I couldn't post this as a Comment as I just registered; so I'm going to post it as an Answer and hope it is okay.)

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed now. Reposting a comment from the issue linked to above by @TechLeadAA

> The total amount of ratings is now generally available for all Places
>   API clients as part of the Basic SKU:
>
> https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields
>   https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields#basic
>
> Places API: user_ratings_total
>
> Places SDK for iOS: GMSPlaceFieldUserRatingsTotal
>
> Places SDK for Android: Place.Field.USER_RATINGS_TOTAL

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, and it looks like total number of reviews from Google Places API is not the same as Google My Business API:

[https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-My-Business-API/Total-Reviews-are-no-longer-getting-in-Google-Places-API-and/td-p/573090#][1]