# Total number of Google Reviews using Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

Now that Google deprecated the **user_ratings_total** variable in Google Places API, is there a way to get the total number of ratings for a particular business?

I see the answer here [user_ratings_total No longer available in google places API. Alternative for getting total number of reviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419487/user-ratings-total-no-longer-available-in-google-places-api-alternative-for-get) , but it suggests using Google My Business API, not Google Places API.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. This is currently, the fifth most demanded feature request for Google Maps API, but still nothing from Google. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:PlacesAPI%20type:Enhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Jan 2019 it is possible to get the total number of reviews using Place Details APIs call (*user_ratings_total* field): https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there's no means to retrieve total user reviews anymore. Below is a list of issue trackers requesting that `user_ratings_total` be added. The oldest one appears to date back to 2011.

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/35820858

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/35821787

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/35823510

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/35828637

Not only has `user_ratings_total` been removed. But there seems to be no explanation as to why it has been removed. Odds are that Google has no interest in fixing the issue.

**EDIT**: as of 2019, it's now available in the Google Places API. See answers above.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like we all need to find a way to work without the user_ratings_total.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone ended up finding a workaround to get a counts of all the reviews? -- or knows of a way to retrieve more than 5 reviews? (...which obviously could be counted for the total)

Answer (score 4):

Just reporting that this is fixed now. Reposting a comment from the [Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820858#comment271):

> The total amount of ratings is now generally available for all Places
>   API clients as part of the Basic SKU:
>
> https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields
>   https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields#basic
>
> Places API: user_ratings_total
>
> Places SDK for Android: Place.Field.USER_RATINGS_TOTAL
>
> Places SDK for iOS: GMSPlaceFieldUserRatingsTotal

Comment: Their initial announcement and documentation was incorrect. This field is actually counted as part of the Atmosphere SKU, and you'll be charged for that if you request this field. Folks who were only requesting user_ratings_total and not other Atmosphere data should be able to request a refund.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820858#comment275

Answer (score 0):

Get total review of Google:

```
const placeId = "YOUR_PLACE_ID";
const apiKey = "YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY";

api = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${placeId}&fields=user_ratings_total&key=${apiKey}`
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**