# Total Reviews are no longer getting in Google Places API, and Method Not Found in Google My Business API

Tags: google-places-api, client-library, google-my-business-api

Since May 25, 2016, Total reviews count are not getting in Google Places API. After doing homework in fixing this issue, I came to know that Google My Business API is the suggested solution.

When I tried Google My Business API and make a request on Https as described in their Get Started Guides.

I got the following message on OAuth 2.0 Playground

[image: Error Message from OAuth 2.0 Playground]

I have also tried using client libraries and download C# client library, but unable to open it in VS 2013 as it suggest that my target framework is not set to .Net framework 4.5 but when i checked in my project it is set to 4.5

If anyone has fixed this issue or found an alternative solution to get Total Reviews Count Kindly share your knowledge.

As i already have spend atleast 4 days for this issue.

Comment: Did you request access to the Google My Business API?  https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#request-access-to-the-api.  That page says "**Note:** The Google My Business API will not appear in the following steps until your project has been whitelisted."

Comment: Yes Google My Business API is enabled on my developer account.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue now.

Comment: @BakerStreetSystems Yes at that time i found a solution. You have to send a request to get all the store. Then send a second request to get the information of specific store. I am not sure that if they have changed it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up that this has been fixed as reported in the Google Issue Tracker for [the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820858#comment271)